# How to restore the aborted or interrupted "git clone"?

Tags: git, github

```
remote: Finding bitmap roots...
remote: Counting objects: 2369143, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (497789/497789), done.
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 20085 GiB | 249 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I tried to clone a git repository from github, but suddenly aborted after pulling about about 60%. Redoing this will be pain because it downloaded around 1.5GiB of content.

**Is there any way to clone it from the point where it aborted ?**

Comment: Do you still have the partial pack file? It may be possible to repair that, or at least extract the completely downloaded objects locally, so that the next pull knows it doesn't need to fetch them again.

Comment: @Rup Do you mean .git folder inside the cloned directory?

Comment: I mean a pack-xxxx.pack file (where xxxx is a SHA-sum) that you'll find in .git/objects/pack. If you don't have anything in .git/objects, or if your .git directory isn't a few hundred megabytes already, then .git has deleted the partial download and you're unlikely to be able to recover it.

Comment: Unfortunately git deletes before while aborting the clone :(. Is there any other way to do restore?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. But it was once I press `Ctrl+c` .
Then I tried with below, and it worked for me. But I done know what its real impact is. Just try and let us know.

put below where you want to resume.

```
git checkout master -- .
```

Comment: Git does not have per-folder operations.

Comment: This would only work when the fetch was already done and the operation was aborted during the checkout. However when the fetch did not finish, git does not have the content to check out yet, so it can't do anything.